# How to make the smoke become a mask layer?

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, editing, transitions

Im a beginner in video editing industry, so I got one main question and few sub questions based on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpWBeSCSemg):

**Main question** - The intro title cover by smoke effect, when the smoke effect pass by then it reveal the text, after that it become a shape. How are those done?

**Sub question**

- how the background been made? it is like a curtain and keep moving, is that made by After Effect or others software?
- at 0:04 when the food shown up, how is the small sparkling effect that surrounding the food?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab a pre-keyed smoke element from somewhere. Mask the smoke element as desired.
Copy that mask onto the text or you can parent the mask as an adjustment layer. Keyframe opacity of text, linear wipe with feather in a gradient/ramp solid for the background.

The "sparkling" effects are lens flares (see JJ Abrams)

The curtain moving effect could be just another preset with the layer style set to overlay. Or you can generate your own layer like that using fractal noise.